How to restore the magnetism on a fridge door joint
Current refrigerator's doors are close with a magnetic seal which is attracted to the doorframe. This magnetism seem to weaken with time. I have a fridge which lost most of it, so that is doesn't even host against the door switch. So I tried to restore it by rubbing a strong magnet on it. I tried two different approaches, either pole on flat, or both poles on each border, but none of them worked. On the contrary, it just ruined the little remaining magnetism.
Any idea about how to address this problem ?

Most likely the door seal has gone hard, so replace the door seal - more flexible with a new magnet as a bonus.

You are probably right and that's the second option, but I'm not sure if I will be able to find the right door seal for that fridge and first of all, I'd like to find out how the restore the magnetism.

Visit the manufacturer's website for replacement parts of the model.

Agree with Solar Mike (always a good idea IMHO!). Note that magnets of that type do not "lose" their magnetism over time, but that the attraction of a magnet to a piece of steel drops as the third power of the gap distance between the magnet and the steel part. So as the magnet strip's ability to conform to the exact profile of the steel door frame decreases, its magnetic "grab" will fall significantly.

You smooth talker ! and the plus one is for the technical bit...
